# AHK Script Regularly Stops Responding

Tags: autohotkey

I've got a simple script that I use for text expansion. The layout is similar to the following:

```
::.sig::
    SendInput This Is My Signature
Return
```

For some reason, this script regularly stops responding. When I type `.sig` and insert whitespace, there is no visible action taken. If I right-click the AutoHotKey icon in the notification area and select the `Reload Script` menu item, it starts working again for another few expansions, then it'll stop again.

I've run it in debug mode via SciTE4AutoHotkey, and there's no failure caught. Can anyone recommend further troubleshooting steps that I could take?

Comment: Without seeing the script, it's hard to say, what's wrong. The most common cause is a missing Return (The script doesn't return from a subroutine to which execution had previously jumped). Or the script might require [administrator privileges](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs) to function properly (if another program running is elevated)...

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, given my use case of boiler plate responses, there's a lot of potentially sensitive information in there which I can't post. I can look into reproducing the problem with another script; perhaps that would be sufficient. I can say that the snippet that I posted truly is representative of the structure. There's no control flow, just three blocks with different text inside the function definition.

Is there any way to see if AHK might be missing the inputs which are intended to trigger the script? Perhaps a hook is going stale or something?

Comment: Why not use two scripts? They won't bite each other, move 50% to a new script and run both. At some point you will see which one stops working. If it is the same each one, move a few hotstrings from the NOT working one to the working one and so on. At some point you will find the "one" that may have an error. Alternative: Add a SetTimer to the script to automatically Reload (that is a command) the script every five minutes or so.

Comment: Something that used to bite me a lot with adding more stuff to a multi-function script was either not having an #IfWinActive statement in front of a block of code or not having an #IfWinActive at the very end of the script (which corrected for other problems at the time, I'm not sure if that's still an issue).  Neither of these sound like your particular problem, but extra #IfWinActive statements don't hurt anything and can keep things from inadvertently breaking.

Comment: Another troubleshooting thing to do might be to open the script that's running via the tray and look at last lines executed to see if the script is stuck somewhere else and hasn't returned

Comment: Great ideas. Thanks, everyone. I'll report back with what I find.